# JSON formatting and parsing error

Tags: javascript, json

```
<script>

var data =
{
    "displays": [
        {
            "ID": "display1",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 700,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display2",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 100,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display3",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 2200,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display4",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 20,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display5",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 100,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display6",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 2,
            "STEP": 0
        }
    ]
}

var arr = JSON.parse(data);
alert(arr.displays[0].ID);

</script>
```

This is a piece of JavaScript that uses JSON to store some objects I wrote. However, the alert does not work, does that mean my JSON format is incorrect? But it has passed several online validators.

Comment: that's not json. that's actually just javascript. you're trying to json-parse what is ALREADY a js object. json is how you load external data into JS script. json-embedded-in-js-code is really just javascript code already, and got "parsed" with the rest of the code.

Comment: please always try to add a language tag

Comment: Ok, that's why, thank you guys

Comment: var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); // I changed this line here at bottom of your code and your code will work. i tested it.

Comment: <script language="javascript"> //code goes here </script>  use language attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a piece of JavaScript that uses JSON to store some objects I wrote.

No it isn't. It's *JavaScript source code*. JSON is a *textual* notation for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and *not* dealing with a string, you're not dealing with JSON.

You're trying to parse an object as a string. When you do `JSON.parse(data)`, `JSON.parse` does a "to string" operation on the object, resulting in the string `"[object Object]"`. Then `JSON.parse` tries to parse it, which fails, because that's not valid JSON.

Just drop the parsing:

```
var data = {
    // ...
};
alert(data.displays[0].ID);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use JSON.stringify(data) before parsing data
**JavaScript**

```
var data =
{
    "displays": [
        {
            "ID": "display1",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 700,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display2",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 100,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display3",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 2200,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display4",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 20,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display5",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 100,
            "STEP": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "display6",
            "curValue": 0,
            "ENDVALUE": 2,
            "STEP": 0
        }
    ]
};

var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
alert(arr.displays[0].ID);

</script>
```

Comment: var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); // I changed this line here bottom of your code and your code will work. i tested it.